# Edit fields of a configuration on another screen

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need help I want to edit a specific field that comes from another screen of a configuration.
I've tried the way I know but it doesn't work.
Could you tell me if it's possible to make this field editable?

Screenshot:
This is the settings screen, within it is a red highlight that I want to edit on another screen.

[image]

In this screen i show what cannot be edited and i have used this command.

[image]

```
    public virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<INKitSpecStkDet> e)
      {

        var row = (INKitSpecStkDet)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            Base.Components.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<INKitSpecStkDet.allowSubstitution>(e.Cache, e.Row, true);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<INKitSpecStkDet.allowQtyVariation>(e.Cache, e.Row,true);

        }
 }
```

I look forward to your recommendations, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The fields that you are looking to edit, are those coming from a Joined DAC in the Components view? The fields from the Joined DAC are usually read only. And if you need to edit the fields of the Joined DAC, declare another view with the joined DAC as the main DAC in that view. Then you will be able to do a select on that view, access the fields and update.